# Queue sorting in python AI

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search, best-first-search

I'm trying to implement Best First Algorithm as a solution to a building evacuation project.

The building has 4 floors, the roof, and floor 0.
We're using functions like go_to_roof for the movement of the elevator in each repetition until the goal has been met.

The goal is for the elevator to stay on the roof, and for all the residents to have evacuated.

The main looks like this

```
def main():

initial_state = [0, 9, 4, 12, 7, 0]
goal = [5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]


""" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
**** starting search
**** έναρξη αναζήτησης
"""

print('____BEGIN__SEARCHING____')
method = input("Enter the search method (BFS / DFS / BEFS): ").upper()
if method not in ['BFS', 'DFS', 'BEFS']:
    print("Error: Invalid method.")
    return

find_solution(make_front(initial_state), make_queue(initial_state), [], goal, method)
```

So basically, using BFS, DFS and Best First I'm supposed to traverse all situations generated by each one. When i run BFS i get:
*GOAL_FOUND*
[5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[[0, 9, 4, 12, 7, 0], [4, 9, 4, 12, 0, 7], [1, 8, 4, 12, 0, 8], [5, 8, 4, 12, 0, 0], [3, 8, 4, 4, 0, 8], [5, 8, 4, 4, 0, 0], [3, 8, 4, 0, 0, 4], [2, 8, 0, 0, 0, 8], [5, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8], [5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

For Best First, I have to use an heuristic criterion.

When using best first you're supposed to add the children at the front of the path, hence the insert(0, child) and then sort them based on an heuristic criterion.

As the criterion, I've chosen the least sum of states[1:5]
State[-1] is the floor of the elevator at all times, state[1] - state[5] are the number of residents on each floor and on the roof.

For example, a state looks like this

```
def go_to_floor1(state):
    if state[-1]<8 and state[1]>0:
        if state[1]>8-state[-1]:
            new_state = [1] + [state[1] + state[-1] - 8] + [state[2]] + [state[3]] + [state[4]] + [8]
        else:
            new_state = [1] + [0] + [state[2]] + [state[3]] + [state[4]] + [state[1] + state[-1]]
        return new_state
```

Hence, the heuristic criterion is this:

```
def sum_state(state):
        return sum(state[1:5])
```

For the front I'll include here the ones for BFS and DFS so you can understand what i'm going for

```
def expand_front(front, method):  
    if method=='DFS':        
        if front:
            print("Front:")
            print(front)
            node=front.pop(0)
            for child in find_children(node):     
                front.insert(0,child)
                
    elif method=='BFS':
        if front:
            print("Front:")
            print(front)
            node=front.pop(0)
            for child in find_children(node):     
                front.append(child)

    elif method == 'BEFS':
        if front:
            print("Front:")
            print(front)
            node = front.pop(0)
            for child in find_children(node):
                front.insert(0,child)
                front.sort(key=sum_state) 
                
    return front
```

Finally, for queue, I don't know where I'm supposed to do the sorting

```
def extend_queue(queue, method):
    if method == 'DFS':
        print("Queue:")
        print(queue)
        node = queue.pop(0)
        queue_copy = copy.deepcopy(queue)
        children = find_children(node[-1])
        for child in children:
            path = copy.deepcopy(node)
            path.append(child)
            queue_copy.insert(0, path)

    elif method == 'BFS':
        print("Queue:")
        print(queue)
        node = queue.pop(0)
        queue_copy = copy.deepcopy(queue)
        children = find_children(node[-1])
        for child in children:
            path = copy.deepcopy(node)
            path.append(child)
            queue_copy.append(path)

    elif method == 'BEFS':
        print("Queue:")
        print(queue)
        node = queue.pop(0)
        queue_copy = copy.deepcopy(queue)
        children = find_children(node[-1])
        for child in children:
            path = copy.deepcopy(node)
            path.append(child)
            queue_copy.append(path)
            queue_copy.sort(key=sum_state)
    
    return queue_copy
```

So, im almost certain my sort implementation on the expand front is correct, but i dont know how to handle the queue

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

dont sort queue like this, also u append on queue copy in bestfs when u shouldnt (re papara ti kaneis mas kaneis olous expose)

Comment: KAI POU NA KANW SORT DHLADH..... Kai an kanw insert den douleuei ive tried

Comment: aaaa basika dikio exeis to eixa allaksei kai eixa kanei insert!! PES GIA TO SORT OMWS

Comment: epishs sto neo version exw kanei sort to path hope thats correct